# Tracking an object's location during each frame

Tags: python

I am trying to get an empty's speed, so I needed to get the distance covered.

```
# Projectile Location at 1 Frame
x1, y1, z1 = obj.location[0], obj.location[1], obj.location[2]

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(var)

currentFrame = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_current
bpy.context.scene.update()

# Projectile Location at the next frame
x2, y2, z2 = obj.location[0], obj.location[1], obj.location[2]

# Distance Calculations
x = math.pow((x2 - x1),2) 
y = math.pow((y2 - y1),2)
z = math.pow((z2 - z1),2)

dist = math.sqrt(x+y+z)

#Speed calculation using 1 60FPS frame as time.
speed = dist/0.0166666667

print(f"{currentFrame}: {speed} | {x1}, {y1}, {z1} | {x2}, {y2}, {z2}")
```

The above is iterated 250 times (the amount of frames there are)

What ends up happening is the speed is 0 because x2, y2, and z2 are the same as x1, y1, z1. The current frame, however, prints a sequence of frames from 1-249. Why does my frames update, but not my coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get an objects position by this script:

```
for i in range(50):
    
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i)
    
    print (i, "x:", ob.matrix_world[0][3], "y:", ob.matrix_world[1][3], "z:", ob.matrix_world[2][3])
```

I think now you can adapt it to your needs just by settings the frame to (i-1) and then you can subtract both locations so you will have the travelled distance. With this you can calculate the speed.